# dot net:i need to parse pdf file to get each article with its title?

Tags: .net, pdf, parsing, title, ifilter

i want to parse pdf file such that i can identify each article's title and its description.so that i can store title text and descriptiontext  in cache for search purpose.is there any library or tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can install [Adobe Pdf IFilter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611) dll. Then you can read properties from any .pdf file using [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx) (Using IFilter in C#). Or alternatively you can also look into [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilterReader.aspx) (Implementing a TextReader to extract various files contents using IFilter).